# поразрядное сложение и вычитание,си

Tags: c

**Объясните пожалуйста**, нужно написать функции для поразрядного сложения и **вычитания** длинных целых чисел, представленных **строками символов**. Если можно пару примеров, буду благодарен.

Comment: Вспомните сложение и вычитание в столбик. Вот прямо так и делается

Comment: Реализация длинной арифметики есть в OpenSSL, смотрите в районе BN_*

Comment: хотелось бы знать принцип, что имеется ввиду, тем более надо представить это в виде строки,как я понял

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int q=n; q--; )
  if ((d = (res[i] = a[i] + b[i] - '0' + d) > '9' /* assignment */))
    res[i] -= 10;
```

Comment: это сложение в виде строки правильно?

Comment: @Евгений, да, это сложение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, хотя бы `else d = 0;` imho стоит добавить. Еще  я бы обратил внимание ТС на выравнивание по "правому краю".

Comment: @avp, поправил... некоторым образом :)

Answer (score 0):

Нормальное объяснение базовых принципов длинной арифметики есть [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer). Это простейшие реализации, удобные для быстрого кодирования, но, правда, там хранится сразу по несколько цифр в одном int. Аналогично можете сделать и по одной цифре, если так удобнее. Если понадобится, я могу дать ссылки на профессиональную литературу по этой теме.